# Creating an equal height buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Looking to make an **equal height buttons** with center aligned text. I tried multiple methods, the text align in center correctly but the icon do mess up than how it's aligned now.

Note that the symbol '>' used in pseudo element is temporary purpose, I will replace with background custom icon if I find a solution.

Here is the JSFiddle with example - https://jsfiddle.net/bgLjfnds/13/

```
<div class="cont">
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank" class="btn-primary">visit the site</a>
</div>

<div class="cont">
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank" class="btn-primary">visit the full site now go<br>visit the full site</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just move your height property from :after to parent.

Comment: @Yadab, I can height to parent but the text wouldn't be centered.

Comment: Increase you height to 40 px or more. So that your content will fix in center.

Comment: @Yadab, have you tried editing the fiddle, increasing the height wouldn't automatically center the top button. I tried height: 60px;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another layer to the button, and assign a height to it, then center everything inside of it using `align-items: center;`

```css
.cont {
  margin: 20px 10px;
}

.btn-primary {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #626f00;
  
  /* using flex box */
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* assigning height */
  height: 40px;
}

.btn-primary span::after {
  content: '>';
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank" class="btn-primary"><span>visit the site</span></a>
</div>

<div class="cont">
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank" class="btn-primary"><span>visit the full site now go<br>visit the full site</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I am looking for two buttons to be equal height.

Comment: I've edited it, is it what you're looking for?

Comment: I've changed the answer according to your description, please check it again.

Comment: I think this looks correct I will try! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by **CSS flexbox**, without after or before

```css
.cont {
  margin: 20px 10px;
}

.btn-primary {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #626f00;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 
}

.icon {
  margin-left: 15px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you want me to add another 'icon' tag inside the <a> tag ?

Comment: you can do this way. without hassles of pseudo elements.  you are taking about two buttons should same height and equal  .. 
`.cont` make this container display flex. `justify-content: center; align-items: center`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery I'd suggest you use the match-height jquery plugin. it will set height dynamically based on your button text. Otherwise, you have to set the height on the button.

```
Match height Plugin: [https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height]
Codepen Solution: [https://codepen.io/chhiring90/pen/xxRyEWv]
```